# SVG Framer motion - how to specify direction?

Tags: reactjs, animation, svg, next.js, framer-motion

I'm using framer motion to animate an SVG, although I can't control the direction of the animation paths.
Some are left to right some are right to left, how can i control direction?
I tried useMotionValue, tried to animate individually instead but still can't control the direction.

Here's the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  SVGMotionProps,
  motion,
  useMotionValue,
  useTransform,
} from 'framer-motion';

function LogoSvg(props: SVGMotionProps<SVGSVGElement>) {

  const draw = {
    hidden: { pathLength: 0, opacity: 0 },
    visible: (i: number) => {
      const delay = 1 + i * 0.5;
      return {
        pathLength: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        transition: {
          delayChildren: 1,
          pathLength: {
            delay,
            type: 'spring',
            duration: 1.5,
            bounce: 0,
          },
          opacity: { delay, duration: 0.5 },
        },
      };
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.svg
      initial="hidden"
      animate="visible"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      zoomAndPan="magnify"
      viewBox="0 0 375 374.999991"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
      {...props}
    >
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="7a42135cbd">
          <path
            d="M 289.074219 187.5 L 362.574219 187.5 L 362.574219 366.75 L 289.074219 366.75 Z M 289.074219 187.5 "
            clipRule="nonzero"
          />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g clipPath="url(#7a42135cbd)">
        <motion.path
          id="flower"
          variants={draw}
          custom={8}
          fill="#000000"
          d="M 360.996094 298.65625 C 360.625 290.609375 362.476562 283.132812 365.578125 275.957031 C 361.507812 280.738281 360.785156 286.863281 359.675781 292.859375 C 359.472656 291.414062 359.386719 289.996094 359.308594 288.585938 C 359.222656 287.164062 359.132812 285.746094 359.082031 284.328125 C 358.980469 281.328125 358.988281 281.328125 358.335938 280.238281 C 358.246094 282.871094 358.09375 285.304688 358.125 287.730469 C 358.15625 290.160156 358.386719 292.585938 358.523438 295.011719 C 356.902344 292.238281 355.007812 289.957031 352.582031 288.160156 C 350.246094 286.417969 347.882812 284.777344 344.855469 283.683594 C 347.046875 294.238281 350.355469 303.625 358.582031 309.890625 C 357.683594 314.5 356.332031 318.6875 353.996094 322.4375 C 351.46875 326.476562 348.652344 330.25 345.390625 333.625 C 343.03125 336.066406 340.429688 338.140625 337.617188 339.910156 C 337.269531 340.125 336.894531 340.308594 336.535156 340.511719 C 336.675781 339.902344 336.953125 339.492188 337.261719 339.09375 C 338.960938 336.84375 340.726562 334.644531 342.363281 332.355469 C 344.863281 328.859375 346.839844 325.03125 348.136719 320.820312 C 348.6875 319.023438 349.152344 317.183594 348.859375 315.253906 C 348.453125 312.582031 346.738281 311.582031 344.503906 312.757812 C 342.785156 313.664062 341.417969 315.042969 340.253906 316.660156 C 337.378906 320.644531 335.167969 324.996094 334.203125 329.996094 C 334.179688 330.128906 334.148438 330.257812 334.117188 330.390625 L 334.117188 225.738281 C 335.84375 224.75 337.480469 223.84375 339.0625 222.863281 C 343.515625 220.089844 346.847656 216.175781 348.941406 211.058594 C 349.539062 209.609375 349.890625 208.113281 349.542969 206.523438 C 349 204.046875 346.808594 202.953125 344.773438 204.1875 C 344.128906 204.585938 343.5 205.0625 342.984375 205.632812 C 341.492188 207.257812 340.074219 208.945312 338.566406 210.667969 C 340.082031 204.757812 344.535156 201.070312 347.769531 196.433594 C 346.351562 197.480469 344.976562 198.558594 343.769531 199.8125 C 342.515625 201.117188 341.308594 202.507812 340.273438 204.023438 C 339.335938 205.402344 338.65625 206.992188 337.863281 208.5 C 338.472656 204.820312 339.765625 201.367188 339.632812 197.539062 C 338.777344 200.132812 337.910156 202.730469 337.054688 205.328125 C 336.402344 201.351562 335.242188 197.734375 333.210938 194.339844 C 330.105469 198.023438 328.316406 202.203125 326.972656 206.695312 C 326.496094 204.910156 326.257812 203.128906 325.800781 201.417969 C 325.339844 199.703125 324.964844 197.910156 323.730469 196.53125 C 323.835938 197.949219 324.097656 199.324219 324.351562 200.691406 C 324.617188 202.085938 324.882812 203.484375 325.148438 204.910156 C 323.632812 202.953125 322.3125 200.988281 320.738281 199.277344 C 319.183594 197.582031 317.308594 196.28125 315.210938 195.472656 C 317.527344 198.722656 321.070312 200.679688 322.804688 204.484375 C 322.222656 204.242188 321.734375 203.871094 321.226562 203.542969 C 318.964844 202.085938 317.25 203.023438 317.15625 205.878906 C 317.117188 207.125 317.378906 208.441406 317.738281 209.644531 C 319.082031 214.0625 321.417969 217.773438 324.761719 220.691406 C 326.472656 222.171875 328.199219 223.625 329.980469 224.984375 C 330.898438 225.6875 331.492188 226.46875 331.773438 227.492188 L 331.773438 274.5625 C 331.582031 273.796875 331.398438 273.035156 331.226562 272.261719 C 329.972656 266.742188 327.453125 261.960938 323.824219 257.898438 C 322.804688 256.757812 321.5 255.828125 320.183594 255.125 C 318.328125 254.117188 316.648438 255.136719 316.3125 257.378906 C 316.148438 258.488281 316.1875 259.699219 316.402344 260.792969 C 316.964844 263.734375 318.15625 266.425781 319.503906 269.035156 C 321.695312 273.257812 324.648438 276.84375 327.605469 280.433594 C 328.117188 281.066406 328.625 281.707031 329.347656 282.585938 C 321.929688 279.984375 307.503906 264.351562 306.527344 252.5625 C 314.519531 246.074219 317.554688 236.671875 319.453125 226.175781 C 316.515625 227.355469 314.222656 229 311.949219 230.742188 C 309.601562 232.558594 307.792969 234.867188 306.242188 237.558594 C 306.402344 232.636719 306.472656 227.828125 305.78125 223.054688 C 305.652344 223.046875 305.535156 223.046875 305.402344 223.042969 C 305.269531 227.273438 305.128906 231.515625 304.996094 235.753906 C 304.171875 232.792969 303.609375 229.816406 302.847656 226.90625 C 302.074219 223.921875 300.542969 221.363281 298.644531 218.660156 C 299.984375 222.679688 301.40625 226.289062 302.378906 230.035156 C 303.976562 236.195312 304.222656 239.496094 303.671875 241.609375 C 302.601562 238.109375 302.121094 234.460938 300.585938 231.171875 C 301.675781 237.488281 302.859375 243.769531 304.230469 250.015625 C 305.101562 254.023438 305.921875 258.101562 307.792969 261.730469 C 312.675781 271.226562 319.296875 278.894531 328.308594 283.898438 C 329.441406 284.519531 330.59375 285.113281 331.785156 285.742188 L 331.785156 368.21875 L 216.011719 368.21875 L 216.011719 82.808594 L 241.453125 82.808594 L 333.9375 175.292969 L 333.9375 80.464844 L 242.421875 80.464844 L 215.835938 53.898438 L 95.738281 173.996094 L 95.738281 369.390625 L 98.074219 369.390625 L 98.074219 174.960938 L 215.835938 57.203125 L 239.097656 80.464844 L 213.664062 80.464844 L 213.664062 370.5625 L 334.109375 370.5625 L 334.109375 343.394531 C 334.140625 343.378906 334.179688 343.355469 334.210938 343.335938 C 343.265625 339.0625 349.921875 331.828125 355.308594 323.054688 C 357.046875 320.226562 358.347656 317.152344 359.105469 313.839844 C 359.878906 310.429688 360.722656 307.035156 361.363281 303.59375 C 362.300781 298.507812 363.085938 293.390625 363.933594 288.28125 C 363.800781 288.25 363.667969 288.210938 363.535156 288.179688 C 362.683594 291.675781 361.84375 295.164062 360.996094 298.65625 Z M 310.1875 234.441406 C 312.378906 231.945312 315.171875 230.25 317.882812 228.226562 C 317.542969 233.429688 311.886719 245.410156 307.992188 249.078125 C 308.664062 247.613281 309.183594 246.46875 309.714844 245.320312 C 309.605469 245.234375 309.492188 245.15625 309.398438 245.074219 C 308.929688 245.542969 308.460938 246.019531 307.992188 246.488281 C 308.441406 244.125 309.574219 242.078125 310.574219 239.984375 C 311.59375 237.847656 312.601562 235.703125 313.417969 233.445312 C 310.105469 237.429688 307.742188 241.996094 305.902344 246.976562 C 305.863281 242.207031 307.15625 237.910156 310.1875 234.441406 Z M 327.5625 269.605469 C 327.851562 271.15625 328.136719 272.707031 328.429688 274.257812 C 328.328125 274.289062 328.230469 274.328125 328.132812 274.359375 C 327.511719 273.167969 326.882812 271.972656 326.261719 270.773438 C 326.1875 270.8125 326.105469 270.851562 326.027344 270.882812 C 326.535156 272.503906 327.042969 274.132812 327.546875 275.753906 C 327.480469 275.792969 327.402344 275.828125 327.332031 275.867188 C 326.058594 274.152344 324.792969 272.433594 323.527344 270.722656 C 323.449219 270.761719 323.367188 270.8125 323.292969 270.859375 C 323.324219 271.199219 323.355469 271.554688 323.398438 272.011719 C 323.230469 271.964844 323.027344 271.980469 322.964844 271.882812 C 320.707031 268.519531 318.851562 264.9375 317.890625 260.882812 C 317.679688 259.984375 317.59375 259 317.65625 258.082031 C 317.769531 256.429688 318.613281 255.886719 319.9375 256.691406 C 321.0625 257.375 322.183594 258.203125 323.0625 259.210938 C 326.046875 262.65625 328.308594 266.613281 329.511719 271.1875 C 330.359375 274.421875 331.019531 277.730469 331.582031 281.054688 C 330.355469 277.210938 329.746094 273.117188 327.5625 269.605469 Z M 331.582031 82.808594 L 331.582031 169.644531 L 244.746094 82.808594 Z M 337.644531 215.449219 C 339.308594 212.273438 341.0625 209.160156 343.691406 206.769531 C 344.121094 206.378906 344.546875 205.964844 345.015625 205.648438 C 346.707031 204.472656 348.335938 205.410156 348.351562 207.59375 C 348.351562 208.316406 348.183594 209.082031 347.941406 209.761719 C 346.707031 213.15625 344.871094 216.132812 342.265625 218.429688 C 341.144531 219.417969 339.695312 219.980469 338.382812 220.734375 C 338.308594 220.648438 338.21875 220.570312 338.136719 220.488281 C 339.09375 219.449219 340.054688 218.417969 341.011719 217.371094 C 340.957031 217.277344 340.898438 217.175781 340.839844 217.074219 C 339.992188 217.59375 339.144531 218.113281 338.28125 218.632812 C 338.207031 218.578125 338.125 218.527344 338.046875 218.476562 C 338.664062 217.5625 339.269531 216.65625 339.890625 215.746094 C 339.804688 215.648438 339.714844 215.550781 339.621094 215.453125 C 338.972656 216.167969 338.308594 216.878906 337.675781 217.621094 C 337.0625 218.34375 336.484375 219.109375 335.617188 219.679688 C 336.28125 218.273438 336.910156 216.828125 337.644531 215.449219 Z M 328.433594 218.359375 C 327.523438 216.886719 326.609375 215.417969 325.691406 213.933594 C 325.605469 213.992188 325.523438 214.035156 325.433594 214.09375 C 326.308594 216.390625 327.179688 218.703125 328.074219 221.066406 C 326.789062 219.996094 326.074219 218.355469 324.792969 216.847656 C 324.734375 217.390625 324.703125 217.664062 324.679688 217.957031 C 321.214844 215.71875 317.953125 207.890625 319.183594 204.605469 C 320.269531 204.496094 320.992188 205.28125 321.703125 206.015625 C 323.988281 208.367188 325.789062 211.101562 327.15625 214.175781 C 327.738281 215.484375 328.246094 216.835938 328.796875 218.164062 C 328.667969 218.226562 328.550781 218.296875 328.433594 218.359375 Z M 332.429688 208.359375 C 331.460938 212.117188 331.925781 215.929688 331.765625 220.007812 C 331.753906 220.445312 331.726562 220.882812 331.695312 221.324219 C 331.367188 220.628906 331.15625 220.28125 331.023438 219.886719 C 330.257812 217.664062 329.5 215.453125 328.789062 213.210938 C 328.082031 210.984375 328.046875 208.722656 328.5625 206.417969 C 329.402344 202.636719 331.4375 199.488281 332.925781 195.757812 C 336.035156 203.191406 336.230469 210.398438 334.101562 217.582031 C 333.824219 218.527344 333.5 219.46875 333.148438 220.414062 C 332.90625 216.402344 332.671875 212.375 332.429688 208.359375 Z M 335.179688 333.691406 C 335.066406 333.644531 334.9375 333.59375 334.820312 333.558594 C 335.339844 331.359375 335.738281 329.109375 336.425781 326.976562 C 337.585938 323.378906 339.320312 320.085938 341.664062 317.253906 C 342.679688 316.019531 343.957031 314.996094 345.257812 314.121094 C 346.363281 313.378906 347.21875 313.910156 347.382812 315.3125 C 347.492188 316.292969 347.449219 317.34375 347.246094 318.3125 C 346.441406 322.253906 344.710938 325.761719 342.691406 329.105469 C 342.082031 330.117188 341.488281 331.167969 340.726562 332.042969 C 340.1875 332.65625 340.132812 334.210938 338.746094 333.519531 C 338.132812 334.253906 337.511719 334.976562 336.894531 335.710938 C 336.832031 335.671875 336.78125 335.632812 336.71875 335.601562 C 337.28125 334.152344 337.839844 332.703125 338.402344 331.25 C 338.300781 331.175781 338.199219 331.105469 338.09375 331.035156 C 337.695312 331.519531 337.296875 331.992188 336.742188 332.65625 C 336.738281 331.921875 336.730469 331.335938 336.71875 330.746094 C 336.628906 330.730469 336.546875 330.714844 336.453125 330.699219 C 336.035156 331.695312 335.605469 332.695312 335.179688 333.691406 Z M 358.835938 304.277344 C 356.789062 299.046875 354.402344 294.558594 351.203125 290.617188 C 351.078125 290.695312 350.960938 290.761719 350.84375 290.832031 C 352.664062 294.46875 354.484375 298.109375 356.308594 301.738281 C 356.210938 301.816406 356.117188 301.898438 356.035156 301.972656 C 354.984375 300.769531 353.933594 299.578125 352.875 298.375 C 352.785156 298.453125 352.699219 298.539062 352.601562 298.617188 C 354.210938 301.226562 355.808594 303.839844 357.484375 306.578125 C 356.066406 305.957031 354.472656 304.308594 352.46875 300.832031 C 351.128906 298.484375 350.105469 295.929688 349.050781 293.417969 C 348.023438 290.992188 347.015625 288.554688 346.445312 285.867188 C 349.277344 287.691406 352.160156 289.339844 354.4375 291.847656 C 357.265625 294.941406 358.601562 298.84375 359.003906 303.144531 C 359.023438 303.371094 358.941406 303.605469 358.835938 304.277344 Z M 358.835938 304.277344 "
          fillOpacity={1}
          fillRule="nonzero"
        />
      </g>

      <motion.path
        id="line 1"
        variants={draw}
        custom={1}
        strokeLinecap="butt"
        transform="matrix(-0.0049543, -0.749984, 0.749984, -0.0049543, 37.499391, 366.83652)"
        fill="none"
        strokeLinejoin="miter"
        d="M -0.00202386 2.000843 L 302.76502 2.000841 "
        stroke="#000000"
        strokeWidth={4}
        strokeOpacity={1}
        strokeMiterlimit={4}
      />
      <motion.path
        id="line 2"
        variants={draw}
        custom={2}
        strokeLinecap="butt"
        transform="matrix(0.549128, -0.510841, 0.510841, 0.549128, 35.877464, 140.124572)"
        fill="none"
        strokeLinejoin="miter"
        d="M -0.000536939 1.999189 L 272.398412 1.999591 "
        stroke="#000000"
        strokeWidth={4}
        strokeOpacity={1}
        strokeMiterlimit={4}
      />
      <motion.path
        id="line 3"
        variants={draw}
        custom={3}
        strokeLinecap="butt"
        transform="matrix(-0.548771, -0.511225, 0.511225, -0.548771, 333.361739, 140.852012)"
        fill="none"
        strokeLinejoin="miter"
        d="M 0.0018552 1.999299 L 271.476325 2.000597 "
        stroke="#000000"
        strokeWidth={4}
        strokeOpacity={1}
        strokeMiterlimit={4}
      />
      <motion.path
        id="line 4"
        variants={draw}
        custom={4}
        strokeLinecap="butt"
        transform="matrix(0.00028564, 0.75, -0.75, 0.00028564, 335.845295, 36.004117)"
        fill="none"
        strokeLinejoin="miter"
        d="M -0.00104413 2.00206 L 139.702101 1.997975 "
        stroke="#000000"
        strokeWidth={4}
        strokeOpacity={1}
        strokeMiterlimit={4}
      />
      <motion.path
        id="line 5"
        variants={draw}
        custom={5}
        strokeLinecap="butt"
        transform="matrix(0.749991, 0.00376582, -0.00376582, 0.749991, 186.489455, 36.000023)"
        fill="none"
        strokeLinejoin="miter"
        d="M -0.0019401 2.000004 L 199.162036 1.999984 "
        stroke="#000000"
        strokeWidth={4}
        strokeOpacity={1}
        strokeMiterlimit={4}
      />
      <motion.path
        id="line 6"
        variants={draw}
        custom={6}
        strokeLinecap="butt"
        transform="matrix(-0.00273282, 0.749995, -0.749995, -0.00273282, 189.445391, 37.503191)"
        fill="none"
        strokeLinejoin="miter"
        d="M -0.00217499 2.000126 L 439.104925 1.999081 "
        stroke="#000000"
        strokeWidth={4}
        strokeOpacity={1}
        strokeMiterlimit={4}
      />
      <motion.path
        id="line 7"
        variants={draw}
        custom={7}
        strokeLinecap="butt"
        transform="matrix(0.75, 0, 0, 0.75, 185.41098, 365.327261)"
        fill="none"
        strokeLinejoin="miter"
        d="M -0.0010977 2.001152 L 198.63954 2.001152 "
        stroke="#000000"
        strokeWidth={4}
        strokeOpacity={1}
        strokeMiterlimit={4}
      />
    </motion.svg>

  );
}

export default LogoSvg;
```

Thank you!!!

I've tried searching the framer motion docs but couldn't find anything about direction.

Comment: I don't think framer motion can do this. But you can reverse the drawing direction of you paths. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/GRGexdb)

Answer (score -1):

SVG path is defined as sequence of instructions (e.g. draw line to x,y, move 10 px up, etc) and that is what defines its direction. If you wish to animate path from end to start, you'll need to set `pathLength` to `1` and animate `pathOffset` from 1 to 0.

You can find more info (and examples) about animating SVG with framer motion [here](https://blog.noelcserepy.com/how-to-animate-svg-paths-with-framer-motion#heading-basic-examples).